# Error de Gateway Timeout 504

Tags: php, aws, lampp

Cuando realizo una solicitud, me da el siguiente error

**Gateway Timeout
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.**

esto comenzó a suceder al modificar el código fuente al cual le agregue más bucles
el servidor esta en aws Lightsail LAMP(php7.1.28)

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

El motivo debe ser que has generado un bucle infinito, por lo que el servidor nunca termina la operación y acaba retornando un Gateway Timeout 504.

El otro motivo que puede ser es si trabajas con una cantidad muy grande de datos. En ese caso prueba a ampliar el tiempo de espera (timeout) de tu servidor.

- Si es Apache: busca el archivo `httpd.conf` y modifica la variable `TimeOut 600`
- Si es Nginx: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf`:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600; 
proxy_send_timeout 600; 
proxy_read_timeout 600; 
send_timeout 600;
```

También es aconsejable aumentar la variable `max_execution` en `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time 600
```